# How to figure the "iso-level" in MarchingCubes algorithm

Tags: algorithm, marching-cubes

I have been reading as much as I can about how to properly implement the MarchingCubes(MC) algorithm and I believe I understand how it is working. The one thing I am hung up on is how to figure the iso-level and why it is float and what exactly that number signifies. Is that at what the height (y) of a given x,y,z coord? I will be using the algorithm to make smooth destructible terrain in a video game via Unity if that makes an example easier to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Marching cube is an algorithm for reconstructing an iso-surface from volumetric data. For example, you have 4 dimensional data points like P_i(x, y, z, s) where i=0 ~N. The (x, y, z) are regular Cartesian coordinates and s represents a scale value associated with that point. You can use the MC algorithm to construct a surface that has a specific s value (s=s0). Therefore, the iso-level value is typically a floating point value. There are plenty of online articles talking about Marching Cube so I will not elaborate here.